# How to Convert EMLs to PST?

Tags: java, eml, pst

Do any one have the solution that how can I convert my `EMLs` to `PST`. I have searched a lot and couldn't find any suitable solution for JAVA..

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what do you mean by EML and PST? Do you mean Outlook files? If yes, why do you try Java?

Comment: Actually my need it to compress and categorize the EML files that I have which can be done in PST or OSTs,
Why Java, Coz My project uses it :-)

Comment: _"I have searched a lot and couldn't find any suitable solution for JAVA. "_ What did you find? Do you how to read EML? Do you know how to write PST? What's the exact problem?

Comment: I know how to read EMLs but couldn't find any way to put that EML to pst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as I can see you are trying to read emls and then put them to a PST,

You can use [Aspose.Email](https://products.aspose.com/email/java) for that

but for reading EML you can use java mail API.

for example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class EML {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

  String host = "192.168.10.205";
  String from = "test@localhost";
  String to = "test@localhost";

  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

  Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

  File emlFile = new File("message.eml");
  InputStream source = new FileInputStream(emlFile);

  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);

  System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
  System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
  System.out.println("--------------");
  System.out.println("Body : " + message.getContent());
  }
}
```

for adding PST using Aspose.Email

```
PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.create(dir + "archive.pst", 0);
// create a folder at the root of PST
pst.getRootFolder().addSubFolder("Inbox");
// add message to newly created folder
pst.getRootFolder().getSubFolder("Inbox").addMessage(MapiMessage.fromFile(dir + "my.eml"));
```

Hoping this will help you

Happy Coding